# Force immediate DOM update modified with jQuery in long-running function

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-running-processes

I have a javascript that takes about 2 seconds to execute (complex optimization algorithm).
I want to set certain span to "working..." at the beginning of the function.
I observe that the span doesn't change until the end of the function.

How can I force DOM changes propagation? or should I approach this differently all together?

I call the function from onclick on the button.

The function is something like:

```
function optimize() {
    $('#status').text('working...');
    // calculate for 2 seconds
    $('#status').text('done!');
}
```

Comment: That should work.  Could you give a link to the non-functioning code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try wrapping the long running code in a setTimeout call:

```
function optimize() {
    $('#status').text('working...');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        // calculate for 2 seconds
        $('#status').text('done!');
    }, 0);
}
```

This forces a new call stack for the long running code, allowing the repaint (changing of the text) to complete before the new call stack begins execution.